# Make Dynamic Calculations from Keyboard Input with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, calculator

I need a simple calculation script that will take number values entered into an input field and display results dynamically based on predefined set of criteria.

For example, I have a set of fee criteria as follows:

```
0-150 = No charge

150-300 = Display only fixed monthly fee

300-2500 = multiply by 0.002 + fixed monthly fee - 300 = amount

enter amount more than 2500 = multiply by 0.0015 + fixed monthly fee - 300 = amount
```

I need the results displayed dynamically as the user is typing in the input, without pressing a button. I want to use JavaScript/jQuery for this.

How can this be done? I find it hard to set up the code. Please, help me out with directions and examples. Or better yet, guide me to the solution that will work as described. Can this be done?

I appreciate your help much and thank you all brave coders taking on this challenge! :)

Comment: `onkeyup` is what you need to look into. Also, JavaScript has issues with Math, so before doing addition or subtraction, you'll want to multiply by `var mp = Math.pow(10, 17)` then divide by `mp` to bring it back to a decimal.

Comment: what is `fixed monthly fee` here?

Comment: Here's a very simple example: https://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/oep9cccy/

Comment: @Thaadikkaaran The fixed monthly fee is 19.95

Comment: @Derek 朕會功夫  That's great example. Thank you! However, I don't have React.js integrated in the website, only jQuery

Comment: @ivetame I'm personally not a big fan of jQuery, but this should do it: https://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/nh583k8e/

Comment: The _inBetween function doesn't work properly in this case. Maybe using if - else statements will be simpler?

Answer (score 0):

Got it. So the function is as follows:

```
function calResult(n){
    var fixedMonthlyFee = 9.95;

    if(0 <= n && n <= 150){
         jQuery("#desc").text("No charge");
    }else if(150 <= n && n <= 300) {
        jQuery("#desc").text(fixedMonthlyFee);
    } else if(300 <= n && n <= 2500) {
        jQuery("#desc").text(n * 0.002 * 30 + fixedMonthlyFee);
    } else {
        jQuery("#desc").text(n * 0.0015 * 30 + fixedMonthlyFee);
  }  
}
console.log('--No Erros--');
```

Hope that will be helpful to others!

Comment: How can I integrate the following function in the script above: 

    function roundToTwo(num) {    
    return +(Math.round(num + "e+2")  + "e-2");
    }